# How to serialize list in JSON object

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have a serialised object

```
{
a: “test”,
B[1].Name : “test”,
B[1].Surname : “testing”,
Etc.
```

But when I sent this object in using ajax Post method in cshtml file, my model is setting the list of b to null

When I’m actual fact I am sending data, but not in the correct format for the controller to understand

How do I serialise the object even further to send the correct model to the controller like

```
{
a: “test”,
B: {{ Name : “test”,Surname : “testing”}}
Etc.
```

Comment: What _is_ `B` ? From your first example, it looks like a List of objects? which would be something like `B: [{"Name": "test", "Surname": "testing"}]`. But what do you mean by "how do I serialize"? You don't do it manually, do you?

Comment: *But when I sent this object in using ajax Post method in cshtml file, my model is setting the list of b to null* -- then please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] as suggested in [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem... if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some. But don't just copy in your entire program... Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*  Thanks!

Comment: Also, please let us know what library and .NET / .NET Core versions you are using.  You tagged the question [tag:asp.net-ajax] but this particular library is very old (introduced in [2007](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_AJAX)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically serialize json by using a serialization library, for example [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to).

To serialize a list, just create a list or array of your objects, and give it to the library for serialization

```
public record MyClass(int Age, string  Name)
...
var list = new List<MyClass>(){new (50, "Bilbo"), new (2931 , "Legolas") };
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(list);
```

Resulting in:

```
[
{"Age":50,"Name":"Bilbo"},
{"Age":2931 ,"Name":"Legolas"}
]
```

I.e. an [Json array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) of objects.

I'm not sure what your example is supposed to be, or how you created it, but it does not look like json.